# HTTP error? What should be used for path?

Tags: python, pandas

Im not able to load the population data. How to get this data in tabular form?

```
import datapackage
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'https://datahub.io/core/population/datapackage.json'

# to load Data Package into storage
package = datapackage.Package(data_url)

# to load only tabular data
resources = package.resources
for resource in resources:
    if resource.tabular:
        data = pd.read_csv(resource.descriptor['path'])
        print (data)
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: if the file is a json, u should not be reading it with csv function but the json function.

Comment: Im getting HTTP: forbidden error if execute the code as such. However if change the 'path' in this code to some local path or website url. then too im not able to download. data = pd.read_csv(resource.descriptor['path']). I wanted to download the latest population of all countries data and used this link - https://datahub.io/core/population#python